# Interpolation on 4D data

Tags: matlab, interpolation, curve-fitting

I am trying to perform an interpolation/fit (preferably non-linear, but linear should also be fine) on 4D data. My data has a form of:

```
[a,b,c] = func(input)
```

obviously, `func` is unknown and ultimately data looks like (input, a, b, c):

```
0 -0.1253   0.0341  0.01060

35 -0.0985  0.0176  0.02060

50 -0.0315  -0.0533 0.1118

60 -0.0518  -0.0327 0.03020

80 0.2939   -0.0713 0.05670

100 0.3684  -0.0765 0.06740
```

I take observations at e.g. input = [0, 35, 50, 60, 80, 100] (0 being min and 100 being max; I take 6 samples in between min and max) and then I get corresponding a, b and c values (I understand that 6 sample points are a bad design of experiment so I will extend it in future).

1. I am trying to guess the value of a, b and c at say input = 19? Any pointers?
2. How to estimate goodness of fit in such scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not 4D interpolation, this is 3 times 1D interpolation. You just interpolate `interp1([0 35],[-0.1253 -0.0985],19)` and the same for `b` and `c`.  (`interp1(intput,a,19)`)

Note that for the most basic 1D interpolation **in a mesh grid** (not what you have), you need 2 data points in general. For the most basic 2D interpolation, you need 4 data points. For 3D interpolation, 8 minimum, 4D, 16.... (2^d in general).

Also note that 1D interpolation uses 2 "dims". Because you use one to guide the interpolation, the other one is interpolated. General, with `[v,a,b,c]` data you would use 3D interpolation.

all that said, you do are nto in this case. You have scattered data, not a grid, thus the problem becomes considerably more complicated.

In case you can generate a few more points (not necessarily 16) you can use the function `griddatan` for interpolating scattered data. Note that you can not just say "give me `[a,b,c]` for `input=19`, there could be infinite amount of `a,b,c`s that have that condition. In any case, you always need to give `dim-1` amount of sample points, and get the last one interpolated. Just an advice: this function is computationally and memory-wise very expensive. Do not use for big data points because it will crash your PC.

In the case you want to find a set of parameters that make `input=19` then you are getting to more complicated area. You want to minimise a function `f(x)`, where `x=[a,b,c]` for `f(x)=input`

In math terms:

`argmin_x |f(x)-input|^2= \vec{input}`

this is a harder problem and arguably more mathematics than a programming question. Perhaps a ND bspline fitting of your data would be a good `f`

Comment: Thank you for such a nice explanation. But, Do you think this approach will also work if a, b and c are somehow dependent? E.g. if coefficients (a, b and c) are powers of some polynomial function a*x^1 + b*x^2+c*x^3?

Comment: @user29337 No,  that is why I added the second paragraph to the answer.

Comment: Brilliant concept; I didn't saw this problem in such a conceptual manner. Thank you.
Generating 16 points data is not a problem for me. Assuming that if I have 16 samples, then how can I proceed to get a general model for "func"?

Comment: @user29337 I think you may have the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. What is your objective? To interpolate 4D data, or to create a model that fits your data? Model fitting and interpolation are different techniques.

Comment: Sorry for that. I am looking for interpolation.

Comment: @user29337 I just realised your problem is slightly more complicated, so I updated the question

Comment: There can be multiple possible value of a, b and c iff the function is non-monotonic. If it's a monotonic function then there has to be just one value because of one to one map behaviour of monotonic functions.

Comment: @user29337 yeah, but that information is nowhere to be found in your question. You definetly have the XY problem, as you are not describing your problem, but your attempt of solution (interpolation). If you know your points lie in a hyperplane, then just fit one. You want model fitting, not interpolation